# Saddle point and upper and lower value

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a function defined on $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$, it is easy to see that $$\inf_x\sup_yf(x,y)\geq\sup_y\inf_xf(x,y).$$ Moreover, if
there exists a pair $(x^*,y^*)$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$,$$f(x^*,y)\leq f(x^*,y^*)\leq f(x,y^*),$$
then $$\inf_x\sup_yf(x,y)=\sup_y\inf_xf(x,y).$$
Is the existence of a saddle point $(x^*,y^*)$ also a necessary condition of $$\inf_x\sup_yf(x,y)=\sup_y\inf_xf(x,y)?$$ Thanks!

Comment: For the sufficiency part, there is no restriction on the range of $x$ and $y$. For the necessity part, I am not sure the condition on the range of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint: the answer is positive**

The answer is indeed positive. Unfortunately, the only reference I have is in French: [Wikipedia - Point col](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_col#Propri%C3%A9t%C3%A9s). The English version of the article provides with less content.

The precise result mentioned in that article is:

**Characterization of saddle points**: a couple $(x^*,y^*) \in X \times Y$ is a saddle point for $f$ if and only if $x^*$ is solution of $\inf_x\sup_yf(x,y)$ (primal problem), $y^*$ is solution of $\sup_y\inf_xf(x,y)$ and $\inf_x\sup_yf(x,y)=\sup_y\inf_xf(x,y)$.

Comment: In the English version, the content of Characterization of stool-points is: A couple of points $(\bar {x}, \bar {y})$ is a saddle point of $f$ on $X \times Y$ if and only if, $\bar {x}$ is solution of the primal problem ( P ) , $\bar {y}$ is the solution of the dual problem ( D ) and there is no duality jump. So does this mean the existence of saddle point is only a sufficient condition of no duality jump?